# Automate Import of files

Tags: import

I have a Directory where I store a number of files of the same type (eg .txt). They contain tabled numeric values.
I would like to write a routine to import them automatically and store them in a variable that has the same file name.
Eg, if there is a file named "uno.txt", then I would like to store the content in a variable named "uno".
Manually, I would do `uno=Import[dir<>"uno.txt","Table"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need "FileNames" to read the file names with given extension.

Second, you need to extract the file name, using: "FileNameSplit" and "StringDelete" to delete the extension.

Third, you must create a symbol with the name of the file. Because "Set" (=) does not evaluate its first argument, you need "Evaluate".

Here is an example. For your purpose, you must adapt "dir" and the file name.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
dir = "d:/tmp";
(Evaluate@Symbol[StringDelete[FileNameSplit[#][[-1]], ".txt"]] = Import[#, "Table"]) & /@ FileNames["*.txt", dir]
```

This will create variables with the name of the files and the content of the files.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it this way, although I would advise against such usage:

```
Set[Evaluate@ToExpression[FileBaseName[#]], Import[#, "Table"]] & /@
 FileNames[dir <> "*.txt"]
```

A better way is to import the data, for example, in an association:

```
Association[FileBaseName[#] -> Import[#, "Table"] & /@ FileNames[dir <> "*.txt"]]
```